# How do I make an asyncronous function run as sync in nodejs

Tags: node.js

So, I'm using [enquirer](https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer) and all the functions I'm using are aysncronus but I want them to be syncronous.

```
const { Confirm } = require('enquirer');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

//files1 is an array of files.
files1.forEach(file => {
    const filePrompt = new Confirm({
        name: 'file',
        message: `Would you like to add this to the concatenation list: ${file}?`
    });

    filePrompt.run().then(answer => {
        if (answer) {
             try {
                  fs.appendFileSync('tmp.txt', `file '${file}'`);
             } catch (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  process.exit(1);
             }
         }
    }).catch(console.error);
});
```

By the end, if the user said yes to the file being added it will be appended to the file. I need the function to run syncronously so it finishes before the next prompt starts.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using async-await?

you can check some examples here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

You can put your next prompt inside the try block and it will work synchronously, as it will have to wait for the first prompt to finish (succesfully). But doing so will soon leave you with a terrible callback hell in your code.

According to the library you're using, the Confirm object inherits the Prompt object which implements your `run()`  function as a Promise: https://github.com/enquirer/enquirer/blob/master/lib/prompt.js#L229

So it would be the best to use async/await in your case. If I typed everything correctly, your code should look like this in the end:

```
const { Confirm } = require('enquirer');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

//files1 is an array of files.
files1.forEach(async file => {
    try {
        const filePrompt = new Confirm({
            name: 'file',
            message: `Would you like to add this to the concatenation list: ${file}?`
        });

        const answer = await filePrompt.run();
        if (answer) {
            fs.appendFileSync('tmp.txt', `file '${file}'`);

            // ... your second prompt's logic here
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **async/await** to make your async function wait till the next iteration. Also async/await doesn't works with forEach, So you may need to change your **forEach** to **for..of** loop.

```
const { Confirm } = require('enquirer');
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    try {
        for (let file of files1) {
            const filePrompt = new Confirm({
                name: 'file',
                message: `Would you like to add this to the concatenation list: ${file}?`
            });
            const answer = await filePrompt.run();
            if (answer) {
                fs.appendFileSync('tmp.txt', `file '${file}'`);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();
```

I've wrapped the code in an **iife** function, because await only works inside and async function.

You can check the async/await implementation with loops and more [here](https://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html)

To read more on **iife**, refer [this](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174)

p.s: couldn't get a chance to test the code, so may need some modifications.

Hope this helps :)